# How to successfully logout and navigate back to the main App screen in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need help figuring out the right way to logout and return to the Welcome screen.

Currently, the RootStack queries the redux store for a token, and uses that to determine which group of screens will be available to the user.

If a token exists we go into a TabNavigator called OrgTabs. And that seems to be taking removing the parent navigator. And when I try to logout, the screen I want to navigate to doesn't exist within the navigation object.

Please help! I'd really appreciate

Rootstack.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

//screens
import Welcome from '../screens/Welcome';
import SignIn from '../screens/SignIn';

import UserSignIn from '../screens/UserSignIn.js';

import StaffSignIn from '../screens/StaffSignIn';
import StaffSignUp from '../screens/StaffSignUp';

import OrgSignIn from '../screens/OrgSignIn';
import OrgSignUp from '../screens/OrgSignUp';
import OrgHomeScreen from '../screens/org/OrgHomeScreen';

import OrgTabs from '../components/molecules/OrgTabs';
import TestScreen from '../screens/org/TestScreen';

// selecetors and hooks
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectToken, selectRefreshToken } from '../features/user/userSlice';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const RootStack = () => {
    const token = useSelector(selectToken)
    const refreshToken = useSelector(selectRefreshToken)
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: true,
                    headerTitle:'',
                    headerTransparent: true
                }}
            >
                { token ?
                    (<Stack.Group>
                        <Stack.Screen name="OrgTabs" component={OrgTabs} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="TestScreen" component={TestScreen} />

                        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="UserSignIn" component={UserSignIn} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="StaffSignIn" component={StaffSignIn} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="StaffSignUp" component={StaffSignUp} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="OrgSignIn" component={OrgSignIn} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="OrgSignUp" component={OrgSignUp} />

                    </Stack.Group>
                    )

                    :
                    
                    // auth screens
                    (<Stack.Group>
                        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="UserSignIn" component={UserSignIn} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="StaffSignIn" component={StaffSignIn} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="StaffSignUp" component={StaffSignUp} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="OrgSignIn" component={OrgSignIn} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="OrgSignUp" component={OrgSignUp} />
                        <Stack.Screen name="OrgTabs" component={OrgTabs} />
                    </Stack.Group>
                    )
                }
                
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
}

export default RootStack;
```

StaffSignIn.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { 
        LightContainer, PadlessContainer, FlexHoriztal,
        Header1, Header2, Header3, TextLight,
        AppLogo, StlyedButton,
        Pad_h_medium, Pad_h_small, Pad_w_small} from "../styles/styles";
import { TextLink, MsgBox } from "../components/atoms/Atoms";
import { StyldTextInput } from "../components/molecules/Molecules";
import { StyledFormArea } from "../components/organisms/Organisms";
import KeyboardAvoidingWrapper from "../components/organisms/KeyboardAvoidingWrapper";

import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import axios from "axios";
import { setToken } from "../features/user/userSlice";
import {getToken} from "../features/user/User";

const logo_img = require("../assets/logo_red.png");
const chalk = require('chalk');

const StaffSignIn = ({navigation}) => {
    [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");
    [messageStatus, setMessageStatus] = React.useState("failed");
    [hidePassword, setHidePassword] = React.useState(true);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (values, setSubmitting) => {

        const url = "https://dandle.dustinc.dev/signin/staff";
        axios.post(url, values)
        .then( (response) => {
            const result = response.data;
            const {success, user, token, refreshToken} = response.data;
            if(success === true) {
                setMessageStatus("success");
                setMessage("sign in successful");
                storeToken(token, refreshToken);
                
                dispatch(setToken(token));
                navigation.navigate("OrgTabs");
            }
            else if (success === false) {
                setMessageStatus("failed");
                setMessage("sign in failed");
            }
            setSubmitting(false);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            setSubmitting(false);
            // setMessage("Oops! Network error. Try again soon");
            if (err.response.status === 401) {
                setMessage("Invalid username or password");
            }
            else {
                setMessage("Oops! Network error. Try again soon");
            }
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setSubmitting(false);
        });
    }
    
    // function that will store a token and refresh token in react-native-keychain
    async function storeToken (token, refreshToken) {
        SecureStore.setItemAsync("token", token)
        .then(() => {
            SecureStore.setItemAsync("refreshToken", refreshToken)
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(setToken(token));
                dispatch(setToken(refreshToken));
                console.log("\x1b[32m successfully stored token and refresh-token\n");
                console.log("\x1b[0m token: ", token,'\n');
                console.log("refreshToken: ", refreshToken, '\n');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingWrapper>
            <LightContainer>
                <StatusBar style="dark" />
                <PadlessContainer>
                <Pad_h_medium /><Pad_h_medium />
                    <Formik
                        initialValues={{
                            username: "",
                            password: "",
                        }}
                        onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting}) => {
                            handleSubmit(values, setSubmitting);
                        }}
                    >
                        {
                            ({handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, values}) => (
                                <StyledFormArea justify='center'>
                                    <StyldTextInput
                                        label="Username"
                                        placeholder="johndoe"
                                        onChangeText={handleChange("username")}
                                        value={values.username}
                                    />
                                    <StyldTextInput
                                        label="Password"
                                        placeholder="* * * * * * *"
                                        secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
                                        value={values.password}
                                        onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                                        isPassword={true}
                                        hidePassword={hidePassword}
                                        setHidePassword={setHidePassword}
                                    />
                                    <Pad_h_medium /><Pad_h_medium /><Pad_h_medium />
                                    <Pad_h_medium /><Pad_h_medium /><Pad_h_medium />
                                    <MsgBox type={messageStatus}>{message}</MsgBox>
                                    {!isSubmitting && <StlyedButton onPress={handleSubmit} width='100%'>
                                        <TextLight>Sign in</TextLight>
                                    </StlyedButton>}<Pad_h_small />
                                    {isSubmitting && <StlyedButton width='100%' disabled={true}>
                                        <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#fff" />
                                    </StlyedButton>}<Pad_h_small />
                                    
                                    <FlexHoriztal justify='center'>
                                    <Header2>Don't have an account?</Header2>
                                    <TextLink onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('StaffSignUp')}>
                                        <Header2>Register</Header2>
                                    </TextLink>
                                    </FlexHoriztal>
                                </StyledFormArea>
                            )
                        }
                    </Formik>    
                </PadlessContainer>
            </LightContainer>
        </KeyboardAvoidingWrapper>
    );
}

export default StaffSignIn;
```

OrgTabs.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {Octicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';

//screens
import OrgSettings from '../../screens/org/OrgSettings';
import OrgHomeScreen from '../../screens/org/OrgHomeScreen';
import OrgAnalytics from '../../screens/org/OrgAnalytics';
import OrgChat from '../../screens/org/OrgChat';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function OrgTabs() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer 
      independent={true}
    >
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarStyle: {
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: '#f38484', 
            borderTopRightRadius: 2,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 2,
          },
          headerTransparent : true,
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: '#d64547',
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Settings" 
          component={OrgSettings}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => {
              return(
                <Octicons name='gear' size={25} color='white'/>
              )
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Home" 
          component={OrgHomeScreen}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => {
              return(
                <Octicons name='home' size={25} color='white'/>
              )
            }
          }} 
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Chat" 
          component={OrgChat} 
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
              return(
                <Octicons name='comment-discussion' size={25} color='white'/>
              )
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Analytics" 
          component={OrgAnalytics} 
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
              return(
                <Octicons name='graph' size={25} color='white'/>
              )
            }
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: If you could create a minimal reproducible example we can play with will be much easier to give you a hand

Comment: Oh okay, so record the phone screen and share right..?

Comment: It will be better to have code running in something like codesandbox.com or codepen.com. Check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example#:~:text=Minimal%20and%20readable,correctly%20formatted%20on%20Stack%20Overflow.)

Comment: Ohh okay okay. I'll get it in there right away

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-rain-kwxtl
It's failing to install dependency. But all the files are there.

I'll try CodePen now

Comment: @MbamiLuka, https://expo.dev might be a better playground environment for React Native.

Comment: Oh okayy. On it

Comment: Actually, use this instead
https://snack.expo.dev/@git/github.com/Dandle-App/Dandle-Frontend@sprint04

Comment: Not sure why expo snack isn't installing the dependencies. I'll get that sorted and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I came up with, was to display the message "Logged out" and then set the token in redux to Null.
And finally, reload the app using the Updates package, which is part of Expo.

So when you logout, the app is reloaded and the check for a token is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,I Hope it will work.

```
const logout=()=>{
    console.log("logout");
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        .then(keys => AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys)).then(() => navigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: "Login" }], }));
}
```

Comment: In the link below, I replaced the contents of the handleLogout( )
https://github.com/Dandle-App/Dandle-Frontend/blob/mbamiluka/screens/org/OrgSettings.js
But it says "Icannot find navigation variable."